# How to get all input elements from page using only plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android

How to get all input elements from page using only plain JavaScript ( I have only three ) ? I cannot use any framework because I need to use this in android WebView.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("input");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

[documentation](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getElementsByTagNames.html)

Answer (score 2):

Like this (if you need to do it one by one):

**HTML**

```
<input id="username" value="test"></input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var inputUsername = document.getElementById('username');
console.log(inputUsername.value);
```

of like this if you need all of them:

**HTML**

```
<input id="username" value="username"></input>
<input id="password" value="password"></input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var inputUsernames = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, l = inputUsernames.length; i < l; i++)
{
    console.log(inputUsernames[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

```
document.getElementsByTagName(tagname)
```

method which accesses all the elements with the specified tag name. Below links has an example of this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your query.